# Radio function in jQuery POST input

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, jquery-events

Pressing the button Index.php page, through sending the data to the script Resultx.php page, which responds with an asynchronous call on the same page Index.php.

index.php

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
$("#input_form").submit(function(){
    var fett = $("#fett").val();        
    $.ajax({
        url: 'resultx.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: "fett="+fett,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
        $("div#resultx").html(data);
        }  
        });
        
    return false;
}); 
}); 
        
</script>
<form name="testa" id="input_form" action="" method="post" class="form-shorten" onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">
 <input type="text" name="fett" class="form-control input-lg"  id="fett" required><br/> 
    <button name="invio" type="submit" class="btn" value="Send" onclick="loadDoc()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> Send</button>
        </form>
```

I wanted to add options with the "radio function" which may send along with the variable `fett`, also the variable `taskOption` to Resultx.php page.

```
            <p><label class="radio-inline select">
          <input class="radio-inline select" type="radio" name="taskOption" id="taskOption1" value="taskOption1"> option1</label>
         <label class="radio-inline select">
         <input class="radio-inline select" type="radio" name="taskOption" id="taskOption2" value="taskOption2"> option2</label></p>
```

Resultx.php

```
<?php  
$fett = $_POST["fett"];   // ok 
$taskOptionOK = $_POST["taskOption"]; // This is what I need
echo "$fett ";  
echo "$taskOptionOK "; 
?>
```

I know this is trivial but to me jQuery is kryptonite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value of a checked checkbox/radio you can try this:

```
var taskOption = $('input[name=taskOption]:checked').val();
```